# Saving and restoring a class in PHP as an optimisation technique?

Tags: php, data-access

I have a web page in a PHP app that accesses a proprietary format data file, parses it, and generates a result based on user input. It works perfect.

However, the data file is now getting bigger and bigger, and taking longer to parse. User requests are also on the increase.

Before it all gets out of hand, I'm wanting to optimise the app a little without spending too long doing it.

At the moment, the data file is parsed inside a class and that class knows everything about the file.

The output only needs to be accurate to within 4 hours of the data file.

The quickest way to optimise this to me would be to load and parse the file on a cron event each hour and save that data somewhere which the web page can load much faster, thus meaning parsing the file once per hour instead of at every request.

What is the best way of doing this?

I instantly thought "database", but that seems like a lot of work trying to store all the data, and any of the data can change in the file, so rather than trying to compare data I would have to drop the table each hour and repopulate, a chance where the web app could then return incorrect data to the user.

So then I thought is it possible to take a class, save it to disk, and the web app re-load that data into memory when it requires it ? Meaning very little modification of the app (and a small script run on a cron).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could serialize the class but that's not really recommended.

As you're using php and are only interested in the result set then the easiest would be to store the data using uapc, it's just a key/value store in memory.

Example:

```
function GetData() {
    $cached = apc_fetch('myParsedData');
    if(!empty($cached)) {
        return $cached;
    }
    $data = file_get_contents(...);
    $result = Parse($data);
    apc_store('myParsedData', $result, 3600);
    return $result;
}

function Parse($data) {
    //do something
    return $result;
}
```

This will store the data for 3600 seconds, and when it's empty it'll load it from disk.

Comment: Looks like exactly what I'm looking for, but why is serialising the class bad? The class itself is very unlikely to change, and the class definition is likely to change even less. I assume those are the reasons why it's bad? I ask become the class contains multi-dimensional arrays, so data access is like $data[z][y][x]

Comment: Because it is always the data that you're interested in, never the class with the functionality and functions for parsing etc, doesn't work for resources anyway and will throw an exception. what I often do is apc_store("myData", json_encode($myData)) where $myData is an array that represents my data structure.

Comment: Fair enough, the only problem I foresee is that the class contains the data and you access that data through functions of that class, the data isn't publicly exposed so really the cache needs to be part of the class, which isn't a bad idea. The app shouldn't be caching the class, the class should be caching the data.

Comment: It has to be in the class, else it shows you have a bad design, the class is responsible for the data. the class should have 1 function and that is providing your data. Only that class should be doing that and only that (single responsibility principle).

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks, however I used apcu instead of apc, as I've upgraded from PHP 5.3 to PHP 7.1 and it seems APC is old now? plus it seems the store/retrieve works fine with arrays so I passed the array instead of json_encode/decode as I assume that creates less work load?

Comment: APC used to be an opcode cache + key/value store. The opcode cache part is now part of PHP itself, so apcu (u = user cache) is the key/value part without the opcode caching.